# Spring session gets overridden

Tags: spring, session

```
<bean id="userSession" class="com.test.service.beans.UserSession" scope="session">
        <aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>
```

---

```
public class UserSession {

private User currentUser;

/**
 * @return the currentUser
 */
public User getCurrentUser() {
    return currentUser;
}

/**
 * @param currentUser the currentUser to set
 */
public void setCurrentUser(User currentUser) {
    this.currentUser = currentUser;
}
```

In the code to get the current user in the session - I use

```
userFacade.getCurrentUser().getUserType()
```

Accessing the session variable is no problem. But when I try open another browser and login with another user id (user B), the session variable for user A gets overridden with User B information

Comment: The User object is not declared in session scope - should it be?

Answer (score 0):

Which browser?  If it is internet explorer, you only get one session across as many windows as you have open.  Can you try using a different type of browser?  User A in IE and user B in Firefox for example.

Comment: using firefox for both the requests. The User object is not declared in session scope - should it be?

Comment: Firefox shares a session across browsers.  It is working properly if you can't log in with two users from both "browsers."